# Find strings in array using C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I built an app of `Numerology` based on Name.

I'm beginner using `C#.net` and I have trouble of functions when I input name.

It's only 1 character that the program was detected.

For Example : `Jane` is not contained in Arrays but only `J` is contained in Arrays.

I really appreciate if someone gives another simple algorithms.

```
 string[] Array0 = { " " };
        string[] Array1 = { "A", "J", "S" };
        string[] Array2 = { "B", "K", "T" };
        string[] Array3 = { "C", "L", "U" };
        string[] Array4 = { "D", "M", "V" };
        string[] Array5 = { "E", "N", "W" };
        string[] Array6 = { "F", "O", "X" };
        string[] Array7 = { "G", "P", "Y" };
        string[] Array8 = { "H", "Q", "Z" };
        string[] Array9 = { "I", "R" };

        string tempName = Name.ToUpper();

        foreach (string x in Array1) {
            if (x.Contains(tempName))
            {
                Response.Write("Your name is contained in Array");

            }
            else {
                Response.Write("Your name is Not Contained in Array");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<string[]> _array = new List<string[]>() { new string[] {"A", "J", "S"}, new string[] { "B", "K", "T" },new string [] {"C", "L", "U"},
            new string[] {"D", "M", "V"}, new string[] { "E", "N", "W" }, new string[] { "F", "O", "X" },
            new string[] { "G", "P", "Y" },new string[] { "H", "Q", "Z" }, new string[] { "I", "R" }};

bool _result = _array.Select(a => a.Any(s => Name.ToUpper().Contains(s))).FirstOrDefault();

if(_result)
    Response.Write("Your name is contained in Array");
else
    Response.Write("Your name is Not Contained in Array");
```

This code will check for any occurance of `Name` in array list.